# Bash script errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, bpm, beat-detection

I am trying to get all my MP3 to have the BPM registered. I did find software for that via [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/129041/any-beat-detection-software-for-linux).

I installed [bpmdj](http://bpmdj.yellowcouch.org/index.html), `vorbis-tools flac python-mutagen` and copied the bash script from the named Super User question (see below). Now, the problem is that this script gives me two errors:

1. `/home/jeroen/bpmtagging.sh: line 67: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted`HELP')`
2. `/home/jeroen/bpmtagging.sh: line 68: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

These are the last two lines of the script. I assume the script did work for the OP, but now no longer works on Ubuntu 12.04.

I am new to bash scripting, and I tried to find the errors, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

function display_help() {
    cat <<-HELP
            Recursive BPM-writer for multicore CPUs.
            It analyzes BPMs of every media file and writes a correct tag there.
            Usage: $(basename "$0") path [...]
            HELP
    exit 0
    }

[ $# -lt 1 ] && display_help

#=== Requirements
requires="bpmcount mid3v2 vorbiscomment metaflac"
which $requires > /dev/null || { echo "E: These binaries are required: $requires" >&2 ; exit 1; }

#=== Functions

function bpm_read(){
    local file="$1"
    local ext="${file##*.}"
    declare -l ext
    # Detect
    { case "$ext" in
        'mp3')  mid3v2 -l "$file" ;;
        'ogg')  vorbiscomment -l "$file" ;;
        'flac') metaflac --export-tags-to=- "$file" ;;
        esac ; } | fgrep 'BPM=' | cut -d'=' -f2
    }
function bpm_write(){
    local file="$1"
    local bpm="${2%%.*}"
    local ext="${file##*.}"
    declare -l ext
    echo "BPM=$bpm @$file"
    # Write
    case "$ext" in
        'mp3')  mid3v2 --TBPM "$bpm" "$file" ;;
        'ogg')  vorbiscomment -a -t "BPM=$bpm" "$file" ;;
        'flac') metaflac --set-tag="BPM=$bpm" "$file"
                mid3v2 --TBPM "$bpm" "$file" # Need to store to ID3 as well :(
                ;;
        esac
    }

#=== Process
function oneThread(){
    local file="$1"
    #=== Check whether there's an existing BPM
        local bpm=$(bpm_read "$file")
        [ "$bpm" != '' ] && return 0 # there's a nonempty BPM tag
    #=== Detect a new BPM
    # Detect a new bpm
    local bpm=$(bpmcount "$file" | grep '^[0-9]' | cut -f1)
    [ "$bpm" == '' ] && { echo "W: Invalid BPM '$bpm' detected @ $file" >&2 ; return 0 ; } # problems
    # Write it
    bpm_write "$file" "${bpm%%.*}" >/dev/null
    }

NUMCPU="$(grep ^processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l)"
find $@ -type f -regextype posix-awk -iregex '.*\.(mp3|ogg|flac)' \
    | while read file ; do
        [ `jobs -p | wc -l` -ge $NUMCPU ] && wait
        echo "$file"
        oneThread "$file" &
        done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script contains a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells), which is `<<-HELP`. It allows you to include literal strings between two identifiers. This identifier is specified after the `<<`, and it's `HELP`.

In the script you have, there's a special syntax element with a `-` between `<<` and the identifier. It allows the identifier to be recognized even if it's indented by tabs, so you could write:

```
cat <<-HELP
   some indented text
___HELP
```

Here, `___` would be a tab. Now, in your case, it's probably indented by multiple spaces, which is why the end of the heredoc isn't found.

There are two solutions for this:

- Change your indentation from spaces to tabs.
- Move the `HELP` identifier to the start of the line.

---

If you use an editor with proper syntax highlighting (or one that shows spaces vs. tabs), you should see this error:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I changed the spaces to a tab. I doubt I would have found that on my own.

Comment: No problem! Updated my answer with a screenshot from an editor — if it has proper syntax highlighting you'll be able to spot these things!